# How to pass template inside angular material dialog content

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using the Angular material dialog, I have been able to display title and content, but I would like to be able to pass in content as a component, how can I do this?

```
public openModal(){
    this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      autoFocus: false,
      panelClass: ['full-screen-modal'],
      data: {
        title: this.title,
        description: //pass component
        buttonClose: this.buttonName
  },

      }

    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
      <h4 mat-dialog-title>{{ data?.title }}</h4>
      <span class="close" [mat-dialog-close]="false"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div mat-dialog-content class="modal-body">
     <ng-template dynamicLoader #myTemplate="dynamicLoader">
```

TS file

```
import { Component, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ModalDialogData } from './modal-container.model';

@Component({
  selector: `[modal-component]`,
  templateUrl: './modal-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-container.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalComponent  {
  @ViewChild('myTemplate') customTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ModalDialogData) {
  }
}
```

created a directive that makes the ViewContainerRef available in the template:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: `[dynamicLoader]`,
  exportAs: 'dynamicLoader'
})
export class DynamicLoaderDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```